# Affect in something? (a phrase from an older book)

Tags: meaning-in-context, archaicisms, literary-english

Reading an old tale from C.A.Smith, there is the following sentence:

> About him, there was nothing whatever of the lineaments of our own
> period; and he even went so far as to affect in his costume an
> approximation to the garments worn several centuries ago.

While I know "affect" can mean "wear", in this particular sentence, it does not seem to fix. Also I am unsure about the following part - isn't there a comma missing after "costume"?

Comment: @Stockfish Thanks, could you please help me understand it with a bit of rephrasing or other words? I still do not get the meaning..

Comment: @Stockfish There is another definition of _affect_, though. Oxford gives it as 'use, wear, or assume (something) pretentiously or so as to make an impression on others.' He consciously tried to dress in a style resembling the fashions of several centuries before.

Comment: Sometimes the use of comma is dictated purely by the tone of the passage. Here it would impede the steady flow of the sentence, and moreover, a comma would be warranted if something startling was coming the reader's way. Here the writer is merely building up on the previous sentence.

Comment: [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/affect) sense 3: transitive verb 1: to put on a pretense of : FEIGN
_affect indifference, though deeply hurt_ // _He affected a French accent._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The particular sense of [*affect*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/affect#h3) in this sentence comes from the following sense of the word:

> [Merriam-Webster]
> **1** : to put on a pretense of : FEIGN
> // *affect* indifference, though deeply hurt
> // He affected a French accent.

To paraphrase the passage in the quesiton:

> He caused his modern clothes to *affect* a centuries-old appearance.

In short, his clothes are not really centuries old, but he is putting on the pretense of them being so.

---

It's the verb equivalent of the noun [*affectation*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/affectation):

> [Merriam-Webster]
> **1 a** : speech or conduct not natural to oneself : an unnatural form of behavior meant especially to impress others
>        // His French accent is just an *affectation*.

To again paraphrase the passage in the question (albeit losing more detail):

> The centuries-old appearance of his clothes was an *affectation*.

Answer (score 0):

To “affect” an appearance or manner is to adopt it so as to impress or give a false image. Google “affected manner” for examples.

In this case he wore clothes of an earlier period so as to give the impression that he was of that period. He affected the impression by wearing the clothes. In this case wear is not synonymous with affect.

Affect is synonymous with wear when used in sentences such as “he wears/affects the appearance of a military man” or “she wore/affected the appearance of a wronged woman”.

Comment: I didn't say that _affect_ means _wear_, but the word is included in the Oxford definition which I quoted. You can affect a garment or accessory as well as an appearance or manner.

Comment: I was too hasty and have altered my answer.

Comment: Don't you think your precious answer made more sense? The phrase used is "affect in his costume". I don't think it could mean "wear" here.

Comment: Agreed.  Yet another clarification added to my answer.

Comment: @Stockfish You wear costume, don't you?

Comment: @Kate Bunting, Of course, but "affect a costume" and "affect in his costume an approximation" are different things, ain't they? In any event, why do you suppose the other definition of "affect" might not fit here?